# How to display notification on the screen. (firebase)

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

My app is using firebase to push notificacion, the notifications are working fine. What I'm trying to do is to show the notification on the screen like the way snapchat and many app do, but I have no idea how to do it :/

[image]

```
 public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
            super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage); 
                showNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

     public void showNotification(String title, String message) {

            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "MyNotifitcation")
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentText(message);

            NotificationManagerCompat manager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
            manager.notify(999, builder.build());
        }
```

Comment: This method is trigger when your app is in foreground. So try sending data notifications . This will trigger this method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show notification in another section of the application, what you can do is store notifications in local database (realm, room, sqlite) and then, make a screen that show notifications from database.

If you want to do a quick proof of concept, you can store in memory, in a Singleton (only for do a quick proof of concept, please don't use singletons everywhere).